# Is setting Homebrew path in .bashrc on debian safe and valid?

Tags: ubuntu, homebrew

I disliked how I had to run the commands provided by the Homebrew installation instructions to set the PATH of Homebrew each time. I found that if I set the PATH in .profile like it said to on Debian, it would not work. However, if I set the PATH is ~/.bashrc, I can use my Homebrew commands. I am not sure if this is a valid solution because I am unsure if things are set properly, or if I may encounter any issues in the future with this setup. Would love some insight to this decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine to add these commands in `~/.bashrc`; it won’t cause any issue in the future.